# copy a string to an array -- strcpy segfault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am trying to copy a string to an array and print it. It works for the first for loop, but seg faults the second time.

```
main (int argc, char *argv[]){
 int argcIndex;
 char **argumentArray = NULL;

 for(argcIndex=0; argcIndex < argc; argcIndex++){
     argumentArray = (char**) malloc((argc+1)*sizeof(char*));
     argumentArray[argcIndex] = (char*) malloc(((strlen(argv[argcIndex])+1)*sizeof(char)));
     strcpy(argumentArray[argcIndex], argv[argcIndex]); //Works here
     printf("argumentArray[%d]: %s \n", argcIndex, argumentArray[argcIndex]); //Works here
 }

 for(argcIndex=0; argcIndex < argc; argcIndex++){
     //strcpy(argumentArray[argcIndex], argv[argcIndex]); //This gives me a segfault
     printf("argumentArray[%d]: %s \n", argcIndex, argumentArray[argcIndex]); //This will only grab the last string in array
 }
```

}

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @SouravGhosh I took away the cast and the second printf statement still only grabs the last string passed in to the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the allocation for `argumentArray`

```
 argumentArray = (char**) malloc((argc+1)*sizeof(char*));
```

outside the first `for` loop, otherwise, every iteration, you're overwriting (and finally, leaking) the memory.

The problem underneath that is, `malloc()` returns uninitialized memory, and for the last iteration, only one index, `argc-1` is getting *written*, so the content of other *index* remains indeterminate. In the later loop, when you try to use that value, it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said,

- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 in C. There's no point in multiplying anything by it.
- [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).
- instead of `malloc()` and `strcpy()`, you can make use of `strdup()`, if that's available.

  *Note: `strdup()` is not a standard C function, FWIW.*

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something about the malloc statement that was causing the error, but didn't know what. Thank you!